# Any papers on the Lambek graph-$\lambda$ calculus-adjunction and the semantics of the Hindley Milner type system?

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Joachim Lambek has described an adjunction between the category of graphs and the category of positive intuitionistic calculi with iteration, see e. g. [Introduction to Higher Order Categorical Logic](https://doi.org/10.2307/2274784) part 1, chapter 4. For me, as a computer scientist, the cartesian closed functors in the free category of this adjunction seem like a good setting for defining the semantics of the Hindley Milner type system. Has anyone tried this, or anything remotely similar?